# Too much space around proofs

Tags: line-spacing

I wanted to have some space (and no indent) between paragraphs. After doing that with `\parskip`, the space around theorem environments went wrong. I found an answer to that problem here, but the spacing around proofs is still wrong.

How do I fix the spacing around proofs? I'd like it to be the same as around theorems or at least a bit less than now.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parskip}{2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}

\makeatletter
\def\thm@space@setup{%
  \thm@preskip=\parskip
    \thm@postskip=0pt}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\section{A Section}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{thm}
$1+1=2$
\end{thm}

\lipsum[2]

\section{Another Section}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{thm}
$1+2=3$
\end{thm}
\begin{proof}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim erat.
\end{proof}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could see my answer at the link: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357345/vertical-space-between-proof-and-theorem-environments/357349#357349. I believe that the question resembles.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You set `\parskip` to 2ex, then `\baselinestretch` to 1.25. It comes to no surprise you get big vertical spaces.

Comment: @egreg I don't see how to avoid that. Don't I need both to control linespacing inside the paragraph and between paragraphs?

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks so much, your answer works like a charm! I was able to tweak the spacing around proofs to be the same as around theorems and between paragraphs.

Comment: @Leppala I hope I have helped you. Listens also the **egreg** advice that is excellent with LaTeX.